# WCF RIA Services: how can I explicitly set which entities should be generated to the client?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I created a Silverlight WCF RIA enabled application and added a model and a LinqToEntitiesDomainService to the web project.

I want to expose all (or some) of the entities in my model, even tho there is no Select queries available for it in my model.

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIA generates entities based on the following rules. Entities are visible if:

1. They are returned from a query operation (in an IQueryable, IEnumerable, or singular)
2. They can be reached from an entity returned from a query through properties marked with the [Include] attribute

Entities in that latter category may not get EntitySets generated for them in the DomainContext, but should still be generated on the client.